# Java runtime segfaults when saving large data.frame from JRI

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, rjava, large-data

I've followed the rtest.java example code from the rJava installation (/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/examples/rtest.java on Debian and derivatives) for building data.frames from java arrays.

This works well for small data frames (~10000 rows), however when I try to do this in anger (i.e. > 1000000 rows) it causes the java runtime to segfault.

Oddly, I appear to be able to create the data.frame ok (making the usual rniPutXXXArray calls), however when I come to save the data.frame (using an eval, after assigning the data.frame to an R symbol) the issue occurs.

I can see some debug when I make calls to eval on the R engine, however when I go via the low level interface (rniXXX) I get no debug at all.  Is there a way to switch more debug on than I already have?

For what it's worth, here's the top of the segv message.  I can of course provide more detail on request.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1be6259ea5, pid=6898, tid=139758087001856
#
# JRE version: 7.0_03-b21
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea7 2.1.3
# Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux unstable (sid), package 7u3-2.1.3-1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libR.so+0x117ea5]  SET_VECTOR_ELT+0x11f5
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ask on stats-rosuda-devel including the actual code you're using. Note that with RNI calls you're responsible for protection of the objects - unfortunately the example code skips that aspect so what probably happens is that due to the size of your objects the garbage collection occurs before you are done with the construction so some of the objects get collected and thus are invalid and R crashes on you. If you want to be safe, protect the columns and then the generic vector you create out of it.

BTW: It is much safer to use the `org.rosuda.REngine` API instead of using RNI directly. It even provides `REXP.createDataFrame()` method that does all the work for you.